# Erro de ponteiro com chamada dinâmica de bibliotecas

Tags: c

Estou querendo que um método dentro de uma biblioteca dinâmica leia o valore de dentro de um ponteiro usando `dlfcn.h`.

Mas sempre tem erro de memória quando tento acessar o valor dentro do ponteiro.

**main.c**

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    void *handle = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_GLOBAL);
    void (*read)();

    read = dlsym(handle, "check");

    int x = 10;
    read(&x);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**check.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void check(int *i){
    printf("%d\n", *i);
}
```

Para compilar uso:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -O2 check.c -o lib.so
gcc -O2 main.c -o main -ldl
```

Tem algum jeito de conseguir acessar o valor de dentro desse endereço de memória sem usar endereço compartilhado em uma chamada dinâmica de uma biblioteca?

Comment: Que erro que dá? É na chamada de `read(&x)`? Vc checou se o ponteiro tem um valor válido quando retorna da chamada de `dlsym(handle, "check");`? (afinal, se houver um erro na definição do símbolo, essa função [retorna nulo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dlsym.html)) Edite a questão e adicione os detalhes, senão fica difícil alguém te ajudar.

Comment: o erro ocorre no `printf` dentro de `check`, se eu deixar `printf("%d\n", *i);` ele escreve o mesmo valor que estará no main, mas quando eu uso o `*`, da erro de acesso de memória inválido

Comment: Eu sugeri que você *editasse* a questão para adicionar as informações, não que respondesse como comentário. Clique em [edit] e altere no corpo da pergunta. De todas as formas, eu não entendi a distinção que você coloca no seu comentário. O que quer dizer "quando eu uso o `*`"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei em qual momento ocorreu o erro de memória que você falou, mas provavelmente foi na sua chamada à *dlopen()*
Vamos dar uma breve olhada no manual de *dlopen()*    (traduzi apenas o relevante)
`user@host:~$ man 3 dlopen`:

#### ORIGINAL

> ...
>   One of the following two values **must** be included in *flags*:
>   RTLD_LAZY:
>   Perform lazy binding.  Only resolve symbols  as  the  code  that references them is executed.  If the symbol is never referenced, then it is never resolved.  (Lazy binding is performed only  for function  references; references to variables are always immediately bound when the shared  object is  loaded.)   Since  glibc 2.1.1,  this flag is overridden by the effect of the LD_BIND_NOW environment variable.
>   RTLD_NOW:
>                 If  this  value  is  specified,  or  the  environment   variable
>                 LD_BIND_NOW  is  set to a nonempty string, all undefined symbols
>                 in the shared object are resolved before dlopen()  returns.   If
>                 this cannot be done, an error is returned.

#### TRADUZIDO

* Está muito mais para um resumo do que uma tradução :-)

> ...
>   Um dos dois valores abaixo **precisa** ser incluido em *flags*:
>   RTLD_LAZY:
>   Somente resolve os *symbols* quando o código que referencia (faz referência à) estes é executado.
>   RTLD_NOW:
>   Todos os *symbols* não-definidos (como um protótipo de função [veja este link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1386/chapter2-9/index.html)) no *shared object* são resolvidos antes que *dlopen()* retorne.

Como podemos ver, você precisa incluir um desses dois valores acima nas *flags* do *dlopen()*
`void *dlopen( const char *filename, int`**`flags`**`);`
A *flag* *RTLD_GLOBAL* que usou é opcional e no seu caso não é necessária.

### O código ...

---

Alterei alguns nomes para **facilitar** o entendimento. O código está comentado.

main.c `user@host:~$ gcc -ldl -o main main.c`

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle;
    void (*function)();

    int x = 10;

    /* vamos abrir a shared library com dlopen(..., RTLD_NOW)
     * -> RTLD_GLOBAL não é necessário porque você não vai "abrir" um
     *    symbol desta shared library em outra shared library */
    handle = dlopen("./shared.so", RTLD_NOW);
    function = dlsym(handle, "print");
    function(&x);

    /* temos que fechar a shared library :-) */
    dlclose(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

shared.c `user@host:~$ gcc -shared -o shared.so shared.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
print (int *i) {
    printf("%d\n", *i);
}
```

Comment: É realmente estranho mas funcionou, eu já avia testado com `RTLD_NOW`, `RTLD_LAZY`, `RTLD_GLOBAL`, `RTLD_LOCAL` e `RTLD_NEXT` e dava sempre o mesmo erro.